# Dropbox integration with UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, dropbox, sap-fiori

I need to upload file from my account to Dropbox team account. I am not able to do it. I am having `ACCESS_TOKEN` from it which API I need to call to upload file in team account.

I am using following method:

```
var dbxTeam = new DropboxTeam({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
```

But I could not able to find team user details in JSON.

I don't know how to use API listed in Dropbox documentation in UI5.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams

I refer above link.

But I could not able to understand URL structure for getting team member list,
/devices/list_member_devices. Where to pass it in combination of `ACCESS_TOKEN`?

I could not able to understand below code which is there in above URL.

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/devices/list_member_devices \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <get access token>" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{\"team_member_id\": \"dbmid:AAFdgehTzw7WlXhZJsbGCLePe8RvQGYDr-I\",\"include_web_sessions\": true,\"include_desktop_clients\": true,\"include_mobile_clients\": true}"
```

I am having ACCESS_TOKEN of my id, uid and team id, from it how I can have list of team members?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

curl is a command line tool to send http Requests. In UI5 jQuery will do this job for you. I´ll try to translate below the request for you, however without tested it.

```
var token = "Your access token";
var requestJSON = {
     "team_member_id": "your team Id",
     "include_web_sessions": true,
     "include_desktop_clients": true,
     "include_mobile_clients": true
};

var successCallbackFunction = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     // process team list member data here
     // results stored in data
}


jQuery.ajax( "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/devices/list_member_devices", {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    },
    data: requestJSON,
    success: successCallbackFunction 
} )
```

Comment: One small fix, you need to `JSON.stringify()` the `requestJSON`.